# ignoring certain characters with regex

Tags: regex, pcre

I'm reading a text file where I'm adding words to a data structure and I have the following line.

- 'tis the season to read the Qu'ran

I'm trying to use regex to delete the apostrophe from the tis but I want to keep it where it says Quran. I basically want the regex expression to ignore the apostrophe if it is between characters.

I have something like but I'm pretty new to Regex. Any ideas on what I should do or what parts of regex I should look at.

```
('\w)|(\w+'\w+)
```

it highlights the words only with apostrophes but I can't seem to figure out how to "negate" the second expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a regex which will target apostrophe only if it does *not* fall in between two characters:

```
(?<=\s|^)'(?=\w)|(?<=\w)'(?=\s|$)
```

### Demo

Comment: Thanks you so much! I was able to edit this to also find some dashes as well.